# Worhp: Local point of infeasibility

Tags: worhp

I have a problem that is solved successfully with ipopt and fmincon. worhp terminates on local infeasibility. My x0 (init) is feasible.

This may happen with the interior point algorithm, but I expect sqp to always stay in the feasible zone?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe also check the derivatives with WORHP by enabling `CheckValuesDF`, `CheckValuesDG`, `CheckValuesHM`, `CheckStructureDF`, `CheckStructureDG` and `CheckStructureHM` if you provide them. What I am pointing at is that WORHP requires a very special coordinate storage format (in particular for the Hessian). Mistakes here lead to false search directions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, my DG structure was bad.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the approximation error of the QP subproblem this is not something you can expect in general. Consider the problem

[image: formula counter example NLP]

which will have the QP subproblems

[image: formula counter example QP]

for a current `x` and Lagrangian multiplier `lambda`, as can be seen by determining the necessary derivatives. With initial values `x_0 = 0` and `lambda_0 = 1` we have a feasible initial guess. The first QP to be solved is then

[image: formula counter example first QP]

which has the unique solution `d = 2`. Now, depending on the implemented linesearch, the full step might be taken, i.e. the next iterate is `x_1 = x_0 + d`. That means `x_1 = 2` which is not a feasible point anymore. In fact, WORHP's SQP algorithm will iterate like this if you disable the `par.InitialLMest` and eventually find the global optimum at `x = 1`.

Apart from this fundamental property there can also be other effects leading to iterates leaving the feasible set, that will very much be specific to the actual solver implementation. For example numerical inaccuracies, difficulties during the solution of a QP or certain recovery strategies. As to why your problem is not solved successfully using the SQP algorithm of WORHP, I am unable to say much without knowing anything about the problem itself.

Comment: Indeed; I surmised wrongly from experimental observation of fmincon (which actually guarantees only the bounds and not the nonlinear constraints).